# Rigify - pitchipoy Imported mesh collada or wavefront - no mesh movement

Tags: rigging, import, rigify

The models are imported
I set up the armature and then let pitchipoy generate a rig. 
Rig moves nicely but
in Pose mode the mesh doesn't move at all.
The mesh has vertex groups that have been automatically generated.
If I click on "select" for a vertex group nothing lights up in the 3D window. (I expect the vertex groups to show up selected, but they don't)

Any ideas?